# JSON data, need modifications

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I have a problem with converting Json data , I get a list objects with different categories for each category there are two versions , So I need to modify the in a way to get list of objects where each object key is the category and its value is list of its corresponding versions and details.

```json
data = [
         {
            "category1": {
                "name": "category1",
                "id": 1,
                "last_sync_date": "None",
                "version": "Version 1"
            }
        },
        {
            "category1": {
                "name": "category1",
                "id": 2,
                "last_sync_date": "None",
                "version": "Version 2"
            }
        },
         {
          "category2": {
                "name": "category2",
                "id": 1,
                "last_sync_date": "None",
                "version": "Version 1"
            }
        },
        {
            "category3": {
                "name": "category3",
                "id": 2,
                "last_sync_date": "None",
                "version": "Version 2"
            }
        },
]
```

To:

```json
data = {
category1: [
    {
      id: "1",
      name: "category1",
      last_sync_date: "01/01/2022 10:45 AM",
      version: "Version 1"
    },
    {
      id: "2",
      name: "category1",
      last_sync_date: "01/01/2022 10:45 AM",
      version: "Version 2"
    },

  ],
category2:[
{
      id: "3",
      name: "category2",
      last_sync_date: "01/01/2022 10:45 AM",
      version: "Version 1"
    },

],
category3:[
{
      id: "4",
      name: "category3",
      last_sync_date: "01/01/2022 10:45 AM",
      version: "Version 1"
    },

],
}
```

Note: I was able to provide only one unit of data.

Comment: This is not JSON, by the way, it's just an array with objects in it.

Comment: No , There are more categories , I will edit my question.

Comment: You have an error in your start data: the version of item 4 should be 1.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not JSON btw, this is just a JavaScript Array of objects that needs to be converted into another structure.

This can be done with any of the loop logics. I can show you one example with `Array.reduce`

**Logic**

- Loop through `data` array using `Array.reduce`
- Take each object and get the keys of each object.
- Check whether this key exist in out accumulator object
- If the key exist, push the Object to existing key, else create an empty array as the value for that key and push our object to the emty array just created.

```js
const data = [
  {
    category1: { name: "category1", id: 1, last_sync_date: "None", version: "Version 1" },
  },
  {
    category1: { name: "category1", id: 2, last_sync_date: "None", version: "Version 2" },
  },
  {
    category2: { name: "category2", id: 1, last_sync_date: "None", version: "Version 1" },
  },
  {
    category3: { name: "category3", id: 2, last_sync_date: "None", version: "Version 2" },
  },
];
const output = data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const keys = Object.keys(curr);
  keys.forEach((key) => {
    acc[key] = acc[key] || [];
    acc[key].push(curr[key]);
  });
  return acc;
}, {});
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 2):

The following uses `Array#reduce` to enumerate the data. It pulls out the category and the object associated with each item. The objects are then added to a result object, keyed by category and grouped within arrays.

Does this do what you want?

```js
const data = [{
    "category1": {
        "name": "category1",
        "id": 1,
        "last_sync_date": "None",
        "version": "Version 1"
    }
}, {
    "category1": {
        "name": "category1",
        "id": 2,
        "last_sync_date": "None",
        "version": "Version 2"
    }
}, {
    "category2": {
        "name": "category2",
        "id": 1,
        "last_sync_date": "None",
        "version": "Version 1"
    }
}, {
    "category3": {
        "name": "category3",
        "id": 2,
        "last_sync_date": "None",
        "version": "Version 1"
    }
}, ]

const group = (data) =>
    data.reduce((acc, c) => {
        const [[category, value]] = Object.entries(c)
        acc[category] 
            ? acc[category].push(value) 
            : acc[category] = [value]
        return acc
    }, {})

console.log(group(data))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not a JSON structure. Input is an array of objects. According to your description you just want to convert it to another structure.

Here is a sample solution of this problem.

```html
// const data = [{}, {}...]; Input array of objects

const ans = {};
data.map(object => {
    const keys = Object.keys(object);// to get keys of current object
    const firstKey = keys[0];
    const value = object[firstKey];

    if (ans[firstKey] == undefined) {
        ans[firstKey] = [value];
    } else {
        ans[firstKey].push(value);
    }
})

console.log(ans);
```